# Webservices in Django

Tags: python, django, web-services, rest, soap

I want to create a Django based web-service which can return Images. I have some queries regarding same. Also, please consider the fact that I have to call web-service from Android app too.

1. Which protocol should I use SOAP or REST (I have created SOAP web-service earlier in Java) ?
2. Can you suggest few good tutorials for starting with web services in Django?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://tastypieapi.org/

Answer (score 5):

I've been using Django REST Framework. It's really good and you can get started with their tutorials, see here:

http://django-rest-framework.org

Tastypie seems to be really good as well http://tastypieapi.org - you should probably check both to see what you are more confortable with.

You cannot go wrong with any of these. Don't start from scratch.